# How to filter ListView from the user that is logged in?

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview

I want my Android project to have a `ListView` that will able to let the users see their own posts. I have done the one-to-many relationship on my serverside database using the username to determine who is the poster of which post. How can I filter the `ListView` to the corresponding username of the logged in username. I used `SharedPreferences` for login...

well, here are my codes.

## Login

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {


final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
TextView tvRegister;
CheckBox cbRemember;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
boolean checkFlag;
int x = 0;
Toolbar toolbar;
public static final String pref_name = "your shared preference name";
String userId = "userID";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstname);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    tvRegister = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);
    cbRemember = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRemember);
    cbRemember.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    checkFlag = cbRemember.isChecked();

    pref = getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();


    final String username = pref.getString("username", "");
    String password = pref.getString("password", "");

    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    postData.put("username", username);
    postData.put("password", password);

    if (!username.equals("") && (!password.equals(""))) {
        PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
                new AsyncResponse() {
                    @Override
                    public void processFinish(String s) {

                if (s.contains("renter")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);

                    finish();

                } else if (s.contains("owner")) {
                    Log.d(TAG, s);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ownerhome.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                    }
                });
        task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");

    }

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HashMap postData = new HashMap();


            postData.put("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
            postData.put("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));

            PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData,
                    new AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String s) {
                            Log.d(TAG,s);
                            if (s.contains("renter")) {
                                if (checkFlag) {


                                    editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                    editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));


                                    editor.apply();

                                    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("password", ""));
                                }

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListActivity.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();

                            } else if (s.contains("owner")) {

                                if (checkFlag) {


                                    editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                    editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));


                                    editor.apply();
                                }

                                editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));
                                editor.apply();

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ownerhome.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
            task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");
        }
    });

    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    checkFlag = isChecked;
    Log.d(TAG, "checkflag: " + checkFlag);
}


}
```

### Authenticate.php

```
    <?php 
require 'database-config.php';

session_start();


$username = "";
$password = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
$password = $_POST['password'];
}
if (isset ($_SESSION['userID'])){
$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
}


$q = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';

$query = $dbh->prepare($q);

$query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));


if($query->rowCount() == 0){
header('Location: Login.php?err=1');
}else{

$row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
session_regenerate_id();
$_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['userID'];
$_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['roles'];



if( $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "renter"){
echo "renter";

echo $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];



}else if ($_SESSION['sess_userrole'] == "owner"){
echo "owner";

echo $_SESSION['sess_user_id'];


}
}
?>
```

## The listview I wanted to be filtered with who posted it based on who logs in.

### ownerhome

```
public class ownerhome extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
private ArrayList<Cars> carList;
private ListView lvCars;
private FunDapter<Cars> adapter;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ownerhome);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(ownerhome.this));


    lvCars = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvOnwer);

    pref = getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("username", ""));
    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("password", ""));

PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(ownerhome.this, this);

    taskRead.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/user.php");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(ownerhome.this, InsertActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater findMenuItems = getMenuInflater();
    findMenuItems.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.action_logout){
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent in = new Intent(ownerhome.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void processFinish(String s) {
    Log.d(TAG, s);


    carList = new JsonConverter<Cars>().toArrayList(s,Cars.class);

    BindDictionary<Cars> dict = new BindDictionary<Cars>();

    dict.addDynamicImageField(R.id.ivImg, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return product.Image;
        }
    }, new DynamicImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void loadImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, imageView); // Default options will be used

        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarModel, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Car Model: " + product.Car_Model;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCarType, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Car Type: " + product.Car_Type;
        }
    });

    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvCapacity, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Capacity: " + product.Capacity;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvFuelType, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Fuel Type: " + product.FuelType;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPlateNumber, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Plate Number: " + product.PlateNumber;
        }
    });
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvPoster, new StringExtractor<Cars>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Cars product, int position) {
            return "Posted by: " + product.owner;
        }
    });


adapter = new FunDapter<>(
        ownerhome.this, carList, R.layout.layout_list, dict);

lvCars.setAdapter(adapter);
lvCars.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Cars selectedCars = carList.get(position);
    Intent in = new Intent(ownerhome.this, DetailActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("cars", selectedCars);
    startActivity(in);
}
}
```

### user.php

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

session_start();

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cars ORDER BY Car_No DESC "; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

## Cars

```
public class Cars implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("Car_No")
public int Car_No;

@SerializedName("Car_Model")
public String Car_Model;

@SerializedName("Car_Type")
public String Car_Type;

@SerializedName("Capacity")
public  int Capacity;

@SerializedName("Image")
public String Image;

@SerializedName("fuelType")
public String FuelType;

@SerializedName("carPlatenuNumber")
public String PlateNumber;

@SerializedName("owner")
public String owner;

}
```

Comment: Have written some API request to your server side to retrieve data from the database?

Comment: @vovaxo - yes sir I'm getting the data from the database using php sir

Comment: How are you receiving the data? I'm assuming you have the username of the current user, but does each post contain the username that created it? Can you show some code?

Comment: @Bryan - Sure sir I will post my does here. :) I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$GET` for the json filtering.

```
$where = '';
if (isset($_GET['owner'])){
$where = " WHERE owner like '%".addslashes($_GET['owner'])."%'";
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cars ".$where." ORDER BY Car_No DESC";
```

And on the

```
PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(ownerhome.this, this);

taskRead.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/user.php");
```

replace `taskRead.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/user.php");` with `taskRead.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/user.php?"+pref.getString("username", ""));`

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm not understanding your data storage correctly, but I'm assuming you mean you've created some sort of `post` object which has a place to store data, and knows who posted it, `user_id`.

Say you wanted to populate a list view with all posts made by user with id `34`.

Running a query to your server filtering `post`s by `user_id` should return a list of posts by that user.

I.E. `http://[url to your API]/posts?user_id=34` would return a response including all posts with `"user_id"=34`.

Comment: You understand it correctly sir. :D
But I filtered them using usernames because I can't do it with id. The usernames are unique on the db btw. :)

Comment: `I.E. http://[url to your API]/posts?user_id=34 would return a response including all posts with "user_id"=34.` Isn't working filtering my json sir :c

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of filtering a `Collection`. You could even do this server-side if you wanted to. But, since it seems like you want to do it client-side, I will show you how you can filter a list on Android.

Assuming that your `carList` has a `username` field, you can create a new `ArrayList` and populate it with only the `Cars` that contain the correct `username`:

```
String username = pref.getString("username", "");

List<Cars> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

for(Cars car : carList) {
    if(car.owner == username) {
        filteredList.add(car);
    }
}
```

Then you can just use this new `ArrayList` to populate your `ListView`.

Comment: Okay, better question, is your `tbl_cars` from your database the list of "posts" or is that something else?

Comment: Okay, does `tbl_cars` have a "username" field?

Comment: Okay, so if the `tbl_cars` has an "owner" field, then your `Cars` object should have an "owner" field as well, no? Therefore, you can use that field, and compare it to the username of the current user.

Comment: Give the cars object a `getUsername()` method, which returns the `String` from the "owner" field, and compare it to the `username` field that you already have, like I show in the code above.

Comment: Yes, whenever you want to filter the list. This code will just obtain a filtered list based on the username, it is up to you to use it where it makes sense.

Comment: I'm getting annoying to you I know sir I'm sorry Hehe. Should i put the Bind Dictionary inside the if statment? Because its giving me a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Not at all, I'm just trying to understand, though I feel like I'm not helping much. No, the `BindDictionary` should come after the loop. And I believe you would create a new `FunDapter` with the `filteredList`, though I do not have any experience with the library you are using.

Comment: It's giving `NullPointerException` on the for statement sir. :(

Comment: What object is null? Make sure you call this after you have instantiated the `carList`.

Comment: `if (car.owner == username)` is null sir. Yes i called it after the carlist was instantiated.

Comment: @J.Shmoe Well, that means that either your `carList` contains `null` values, or you haven't called `String username = prefs.getString("username", "");`.